# Shofar odor cleaning recommendations

Tags: how-to, shofar, cleaning, smell

How do you remove the odor from inside a shofar?

I have already tried hydrogen peroxide.

Comment: Be careful with using plain H2O2. It's an astringent, and you could harm your lip if there's too much left on the shofar. All you need to do is eliminate an oxygen molecule, and in many cases, that will do a decent job.